# Any other kinds of "Task Queue" APIs?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I'm curious if it's common practice outside of the GAE platform to be able to defer tasks to background workers via webhooks.

I find it particularly useful to speed up the front-end of webapps, by delegating any long process to background tasks.

I'd like to hear about open source software allowing to implement a TaskQueue-like API, with webhooks preferably, if anyone has some experience in this area.

Thanks!

Comment: Amazon just released Simple workflow serice (swf) which you can think of as a more sophisticated/flexible version of GAE Task queues. Checkout http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dg-intro-to-swf.html for overview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree - it's a very useful pattern. It's not yet widespread, but is gaining in popularity as an easy way to defer work.

[RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) is a task queue type service that you can use in any project. [TyphoonAE](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/) uses it to implement the Task Queue API.

Amazon have the [Simple Queue Service](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/), and the new [Simple Notification Service](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/).

Ruby on Rails has [delayed_job](http://adamfortuna.com/2009/08/17/the-amazingness-of-delayed_job-for-rails/), which also served as the inspiration for the App Engine 'deferred' library.

Answer (score 1):

"[Beanstalk](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/) is a fast and easy way to queue background tasks. [Stalker](https://github.com/adamwiggins/stalker) provides a nice wrapper interface for creating these jobs."

And here is the great [introduction](http://railscasts.com/episodes/243-beanstalkd-and-stalker) on Railscasts.com

Other languages [clients](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/wiki/client-libraries) of beanstalk.